# joining timeseries data with spark Dataframe containing time range

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes one that contains event details in the following format (eventData).

```
|id|parameter  |value|eventtime           |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|1 |temperature|23   |2005-Apr-11 11:20:00|
|2 |temperature|21   |2005-Apr-12 14:34:00|
```

and another that contains a time range

Operationdata

```
|operationid|paramter   |start_time          |end_time            |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|1234       |Temperature|2005-Apr-11 10:20:00|2005-Apr-11 12:20:00|
|1235       |Temperature|2005-Apr-12 14:00:00|2005-Apr-11 16:30:00|
```

Now, I would like to join these two dataframes to fetch following output.

```
|operationid|paramter   |value|eventtime           |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|1234       |Temperature|23   |2005-Apr-11 11:20:00|
|1235       |Temperature|21   |2005-Apr-12 14:34:00|
```

I could achieve this using following SQL query

```
joinSQL = sqlContext.sql("select OperationDF.operationid,eventDF.parameter,eventDF.value,eventDF.eventtime from eventDF,OperationDF where eventDF.eventtime >= jdbcDF.start_time AND eventDF.eventtime <= jdbcDF.end_time")
```

This Query returns data in the way I desire, but it does a CartesianProduct between the two dataframes.

OperationDF is actually fetched from RDBMS and I have to do SQLContext.cacheTable on OperationDF to avoid multiple Queries to Database.

I am newbie to spark and My queries right now are

1. is there a better way to do the Join and avoid CartesianProduct
2. Does SQLContext.cacheTable keep the Dataframe content in Driver Memory or will that be distributed over a cluster?
3. If it is held in Driver Memory how can we handle cases where the Dataframe is too big to be held in Driver Memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Does SQLContext.cacheTable keep the Dataframe content in Driver Memory or will that be distributed over a cluster?

Every `DataFrame` or `RDD` is distributed over worker nodes. Unless you `collect` no data should be stored on a driver.

> is there a better way to do the Join and avoid CartesianProduct

Unless internal engine can optimize this type or range joins, and as far as I know at this moment it can't, the answer no.

If you have some additional information which can be used to limit the results (like maximum even span) you improve this using additional predicates.

If not, and you can afford full sort, you can handle this using low level API and / or some combination of window functions.